# Can buraq, the heavenly creature fly?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, source-identification, seerah, islamic-resources

Other questions on this site site suggest buraq was left at aqsa after isra(journey by night on land)

[Did earlier prophets also travel on buraq?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40036/did-earlier-prophets-also-travel-on-buraq)

***If the creature could fly to heavens, it could have flown to aqsa*** why did it do horizon jumps?

In a report its mentioned the next step, the buraq would place was at horizon.

So ultimately the question does the creature buraq fly?

Some scholars said it didnt fly, can someone please post a link. Last I heard was Najdi phase Yasir qadhi used to tell that buraq didnt fly. Unable to find this too.