# Did earlier prophets do meraj in their times?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, prophets, prophet-musa

This question

[Did earlier prophets also travel on buraq?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40036/did-earlier-prophets-also-travel-on-buraq)

tells implicitly that earlier prophets do isra (journey by land)

There is no further information whether isra was succeeded by meraj in their times.

Can the following passage in the report recorded by bukhari be construed as proof for meraj of prophet moses in his time?

> Moses said (to Allah), "O Lord! I thought that none would be raised up above me."

- [Bukhari 7517](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7517)

Answer (score 1):

#### Eraly scholars didn't interpreted Musa's statement as being evidence for M'iraaj

No the statement of Moses (Musa) is no proof for a potential Mi'raj of other prophets.
Because this statement is related to Musa's() position in the heavens as stated in the hadith before your quote:

> ... On each Heaven there were prophets whose names he had mentioned and of whom I remember Idris on the second Heaven, Aaron on the fourth Heavens another prophet whose name I don't remember, on the fifth Heaven, Abraham on the sixth Heaven, **and Moses on the seventh Heaven because of his privilege of talking to Allah directly**. Moses said (to Allah), "O Lord! I thought that none would be raised up above me." ...
> (See full hadith text in [Sahih al-Bukahri](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7517))

And because Allah said in the qur'an:

> [ Allah ] said, "O Moses, I have chosen you over the people with My messages and My words [to you]. So take what I have given you and be among the grateful."
> ([7:144](https://legacy.quran.com/7/144))

Ibn Hajar quoted at this point the following explanation of ibn Battal:
 <sup>In the following I'll be translating from Arabic language, as these translations are mainly of my own with some support by google translate take them with the necessary care.</sup>

> قال ابن بطال: فهم موسى من اختصاصه بكلام الله تعالى له في الدنيا دون غيره من البشر لقوله ﴿إني اصطفيتك على الناس برسالات وبكلامي﴾ أن المراد بالناس هنا البشر كلهم وأنه استحق بذلك أن لا يرفع أحد عليه، فلما فضل الله محمدا عليه عليهما الصلاة والسلام بما أعطاه من المقام المحمود وغيره ارتفع على موسى وغيره بذلك ثم ذكر الاختلاف في أن الله  في ليلة الإسراء كلم محمدا ﷺ بغير واسطة أو بواسطة، والخلاف في وقوع الرؤية للنبي ﷺ بعين رأسه أو بعين قلبه في اليقظة أو في المنام، وقد مضى بيان الاختلاف في ذلك في تفسير سورة النجم بما يغني عن إعادته. ([Source](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/7914#p1))
> Ibn Battal said: Musa understood, from his exclusiveness in the word of Allah the  Almighty to him in this world to the exclusion of other human beings, due to his saying, “*I have chosen you over the people with My messages and with My words,*” that what is meant by people here is all human beings, and that he thus deserved that no one should be exalted above him, so when Allah favored Muhammad, peace and blessings be upon them both. With what he gave of the praiseworthy status and others, he rose above Moses and others in that.
> Then he mentioned the difference in that Allah, on the night of the Night Journey (Israa'), spoke to Muhammad, peace and blessings be upon him, without an intermediary or by means, and the difference in the occurrence of seeing the Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, with the eye of his head (the seeing eye) or with the eye of his heart (the feeling eye), whether awake or in a dream, and the difference has already been explained. This includes the interpretation of Surah Al-Najm in a way that eliminates the need to repeat it.

Note that earlier ibn Hajar even quoted the differences in the riwaya of the hadith according to which Musa's() position or settlement was also mentioned to be in the sixth heaven and that some riwayas even quoted that Ibraheem () was in a higher heaven than Musa ().

#### Did the prophets do Mi'raaj in their times?

To be honest we have no clear textual evidence that they did.
However, one might interpret some verses as such evidence like:

- > [Mention] when Allah said, "O Jesus, indeed I will take you and raise you to Myself and purify you from those who disbelieve and make those who follow you [in submission to Allah alone] superior to those who disbelieve until the Day of Resurrection. Then to Me is your return, and I will judge between you concerning that in which you used to differ. ([3:55](https://legacy.quran.com/3/55))
- > And mention in the Book, Idrees. Indeed, he was a man of truth and a prophet. (56) And We raised him to a high station. ([19:56-57](https://legacy.quran.com/19/56-57))

Nevertheless, the last statement appears in the hadith and was regarded similar to the case above as a description on Idrees's settlement or position in the heavens and closure to Allah the Almighty by earlier scholars.

And further assuming any other prophet was raised to Allah in a manner similar to that of Muhammad () the form of Muhammad's Mi'raj was rather unique as Allah says:

> Then he approached and descended (8) And was at a distance of two bow lengths or nearer. ([53:8-9](https://legacy.quran.com/53/8-9))

Because Allah the Almighty appointed him next to Him to give some revelation and then he returned to his Ummah to spread Allah's message.

Also, note that raising -most likely the souls of- the prophets happened if we assume that the Israa' and Mi'raj happened in the same day since the prophet () led the prayer in front of the other prophets in al-Quds (Jerusalem) or after he led the prayer if it was only part of the Israa' and the date of Mi'raaj was a different day. I honestly didn't check the different scholarly opinions on this topic.

Comment: Upvote for the effort, iblis was raised through heavens, can it taken as meraj?

Comment: @Random_User I don't know what you mean by Iblees was raised through the heavens or what you are referring to. A Mi'raaj of other prophets has no clear backup as already stated. Just because it can be interpreted by one "evidence" doesn't hold since "raise" is only one possibility that can refer to Mi'raaj.